# Add python bot to google extension

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, bots

I wanted to add a web scraping bot made with selenium to my google extensions. I don't seem to find a solution to add the bot to the extensions. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: did you try this?  https://pythonspot.com/create-a-chrome-plugin-with-python/

Comment: Yes, I think that that is the best way of doing it. The problem is that I was told that the best way of doing it was through method B. The problem is that the commends are for linux and I am working on a windows